# Add indented text

Tags: html, css

I would like to indent text and use tab (like the tab key on the key board). But the code below seems to add 4 spaces for the tab and do not indent the text with the row below. You can always use a table to indent the text in nice columns but that is ugly code. This is what I have now:

```
    <style>
    ul li {
    list-style-position: outside;
    }
    
    .tab {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 40px;
        }
  </style>



<h2>Description</h2>
                            <ul>
                                <li><b>Fruit</b>  Bananan <span class="tab"><b>Meat</b> Cow</span></li>
                                <li><b>Drink</b> Irish<span class="tab"><b>Beer</b> Spendrups</span></li>
                                <li><b>Car</b> Tesla<span>&#x09;Type BEV</span></li>
                            </ul>
```

I read that   command should act as a tab key but it doesn't. So how can I get nice indented text with exact columns, without using a table?

Comment: do you mean that you code looks like this in your codding application?

Comment: U wanna the indented text on the IDE or in de web browser?